# Firefox cannot save vine video on Twitter

Tags: firefox, video

When playing a vine video on Twitter, Firefox does not let me save the video with right-click -> save video - the menu item is disabled.

How is this done?

Example: https://twitter.com/SwiftOnSecurity/status/749774085081751552

Comment: What does "vine" mean in this context?

Comment: Vine is a video service which limits clips to 7 second duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the *twitter.com* part to *mobile.twitter.com*. Play the video and then save by right click.